# How to cope with terminal operations in a fluent API?

Tags: java, api-design, builder-pattern

I am trying to polish my [data-mapping library](https://github.com/roookeee/datus/tree/develop) and struggle with my fluent API design as it feels clumsy in some basic use-cases.

The library focuses on defining mapping objects from one type into another in a fluent way, even for immutable objects. The immutable API works as follows: Every constructor parameter has its mapping process defined in declaration order. Said mapping process does not need to start from the current constructor parameters type which leads to the following code (excerpt from [here](https://github.com/roookeee/datus/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/github/roookeee/datus/immutable/BasicImmutableMappingTest.java)), there are more test-cases that show said problem there) :

```
public class Item {
    private final String id;

    public Item(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

//simplified example: the main use case of the library is to map different types to another
Mapper<Item, Item> mapper = new ConstructorBuilder1<Item, String, Item>(Item::new)
            .from(Item::getId).mapTo(Function.identity())
            .build();
```

As you can see even though I have already reached the desired constructor parameters type I still have to call the terminal operation `mapTo(Function.identity())`. Imagine another case where the `.from` calls getter return type is mismatching from the get go.

Is there another, better or more clear approach to avoid this? I want to avoid the unnecessary mapTo-call if possible. Other approaches that circumvent the outlined problem are welcome too.

I already tried overloading which doesn't work well with lambdas and I have documented several other (subjectively less fitting) approaches [here](https://github.com/roookeee/datus/issues/4).

[This](https://github.com/roookeee/datus/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/github/roookeee/datus/api/Datus.java) and its `.immutable`-functions serve as the main entry point into the immutable API.

[This](https://github.com/roookeee/datus/blob/994982e1dbca6b115d6d9f10cfba59bb4741ccee/src/test/java/com/github/roookeee/datus/immutable/HighArgImmutableMapperTest.java#L79) should give a more broad overview of the libraries usage.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: What is your desired goal?  You don't want to have to call the terminal `.mapTo` function at the end?

Comment: That would be for the best yes. I tried like 5 different approaches that didn't work. I am open for different approaches altogether though. Will edit the post.

Comment: Why don't you just add the `mapTo` functionality to your `build()` function or make `mapTo` the last thing you call and skip the `build()` call?

Comment: That would work in the single constructor parameter case, I am supporting up to 8 constructor parameters for now so this is not an option. The main headache I have is that I have to to this unnecessary `Function.identity()` mapping even though the types fit :/ Javas type system is in my way here but I don't want to lose compile time correctness.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that.  You would simply add an additional fluent call for each parameter.

Comment: Ok, so explain to me again why `.mapTo(Function.identity())` cannot be your last function call?

Comment: `mapTo` finishes the mapping definition of the current constructor parameter. Yes, when defining the last constructor parameter `mapTo` could directly return whatever `build()` returns, but the other preceding steps return an object for defining the next constructor parameters mapping definition

Comment: Presumably, once you call mapTo, you're done, right?  You don't need any further constructor definitions?

Comment: Oh, so you need one mapTo for each constructor parameter?

Comment: When passed an 5 argument constructor I require 5 `mapTo` calls which each can have an indefinite amount of preceding `map` steps. One `mapTo` ends exactly one constructor parameter definition.

Comment: Yes, one `mapTo` for each constructor parameter

Comment: Alright.  What prevents you from calling mapTo internally when you chain your `from()` call?

Comment: Javas type system cannot express that. To support having a mismatching intermediate type for the current constructor parameter I need two generic parameters `CurrentType` and `TargetType`. Thus i need a `Function<CurrentType, TagetType>` at the end. I cannot define a function that only works when `CurrentType == TargetType`

Comment: So it's not always going to be `.mapTo(Function.identity())` then?  It could be `.mapTo(Something.else())`?

Comment: No, `mapTo` always expects a `Function<CurrentType, TargetType>`. Contrast that to `map` which expects `Function<CurrentType, SomeOtherType>`. Every constructor parameters definition has to end in a `mapTo`, even when the `.from`-calls type is already matching. Thats the whole problem :)

Comment: So is the function you pass to `.mapTo` responsible for type conversion between the source type and the target type?

Comment: No, let me explain: a mapping process for a given ctor-parameter is defined by an initial getter on the input-type `Function<InputType, SomeType>` in a `from`-call. Then multiple `map`-calls can transform `SomeType` to whatever they want. To finish a mapping process one must supply a function `Function<CurrentType, ConstructorParameterType>` in `mapTo`. This is all fine but really clumsy when the getter supplied to the `from` call already matches `Function<InputType,ConstructorParameterType>` or a `map` already returns a `ConstructorParameterType` value. `mapTo(F.identity())` is needed then.

Comment: Hmm... As a user of your library, I don't think I would mind adding what you consider redundant terminus calls.  It makes everything more explicit, more consistent, and less magical, for the cost of a little bit more "noise."

Comment: It's not like anyone considers java "terse" anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Maybe its time to just let it go and accept this minor grievance. Thanks for your time, I can't believe how fast you were. This is what I came for

Comment: NP.  If you still need to figure this out, consider asking on Stack Overflow.  I think your question is a good candidate for asking there, and code questions, strictly speaking, are off-topic here.  But if you do that, you'll need to provide a reproducible code sample *in the question itself.*  Good luck.